# PostgreSQL Function and trigger in postresql to contain changes

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I want to implement a function and a trigger (without parameters) that allow making changes in a table B as long as they are made in table D. What I mean by changes is insertions, updates or deletions.

For example, if I delete, update or insert a record in table D, I need that it is also done automatically in table B, and return me the new values added.

I have designed this table D in such a way that it has a primary key composed by 3 values that it obtains from other tables (table A, table C and table D).

For example I have;

```
TABLE A
x int (primary key)
y character
z character

TABLE C
a int (primary key)
b character
c character 

TABLE D
x (primary key)
a (primary key)
dd (primary key)
ddd
dddd

TABLE B
x (primary key)
a (primary key)
dd (primary key)
bbb
bbbb
```

The structure should be something similar to the following. I have thought of implementing several TG_OP in function of several IF, but I can't get a satisfactory result.

```
CREATE FUNCTION function()
RETURNS trigger language plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    

RETURN new;
END;
$$;


CREATE TRIGGER trigger
AFTER UPDATE ON table D
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE function();
```

Thank you all

Comment: Why do you have two tables, if they both have same content?  Easier way would be to create a view like `CREATE VIEW B AS SELECT * FROM D;`

Comment: Well, They do not have the same functions. In fact, they have the same composite primary keys, but they have different attributes.

Comment: This smells like adding the fields `bbb` and `bbbb` to the table D (or `ddd` and `dddd` to the table B)  would be a solution too ?

Comment: I agree with @Luuk in that this could be achieved in a simpler way using views and/or foreign keys with [`ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createtable.html#:~:text=REFERENCES%20reftable%20%5B%20(%20refcolumn%20)%20%5D%20%5B%20MATCH%20matchtype,can%20be%20performed%20more%20efficiently.) The question would be a bit clearer if the foreign key references were defined in the code, and primary key definitions moved to a `constraint pkey primary key (x,a,dd)`] at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 3 separated `trigger functions` for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON table D :

```
CREATE FUNCTION tableD_insert()
RETURNS trigger language plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tableB (x, a, dd) VALUES (NEW.x, NEW.a, NEW.dd) ; -- all the other columns of tableB will be empty or automatically fulfilled with their default values
RETURN new;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER tableD_insert
AFTER INSERT ON tableD
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tableD_insert();

CREATE FUNCTION tableD_update()
RETURNS trigger language plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    UPDATE tableB
       SET x = NEW.x, a = NEW.a, dd = NEW.dd
     WHERE x = OLD.x AND a = OLD.a AND dd = OLD.dd ;
RETURN new;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER tableD_update
AFTER UPDATE ON table D OF x, a, dd
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tableD_update();

CREATE FUNCTION tableD_delete()
RETURNS trigger language plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM tableB
     WHERE x = OLD.x AND a = OLD.a AND dd = OLD.dd ;
RETURN old;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER tableD_delete
AFTER DELETE ON tableD
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tableD_delete();
```

Comment: Hi Edouard! Thank you for your response. There is no way to do it in a more compressed form?

Comment: no way, the sql statements are different from each others and must be associated to the rigth trigger.

Comment: @yuda This is actually pretty minimal, there are only 3 lines of actual logic here. The rest is just necessary syntax required to put that logic in the right place, and formatting for readability.